# can somebody explain how self.nextNode.remove(data,self) call remove() method?

Tags: python, data-structures

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.nextNode=None
    def remove(self,data,previousNode):
        if self.data == data:
            previousNode.nextNode=self.nextNode
            del self.data
            del self.nextNode
        else:
            if self.nextNode is not None:
                self.nextNode.remove(data,self)
```

Comment: You don't have to `del self.data` and `del self.nextNode`... but that being said, what exactly are you asking? What is it that you don't understand? Please elaborate on your title in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a node in a linked list.

```
    def remove(self,data,previousNode):
        if self.data == data: # we hit the node we want to delete
            previousNode.nextNode=self.nextNode # we disconnect the current node from the link, connect the next node to its previous node
            del self.data # not exactly sure about these two lines
            del self.nextNode
        else: # we haven't hit the node we want to delete
            if self.nextNode is not None: # the list hasn't end, there is a "next"
                self.nextNode.remove(data, self)
                # this is the tricky part, 
                # you need to consider this in nextNode's perspective. 
                # You're calling nextNode's remove method, 
                # telling it the data you need to remove, and tell it 
                # that it's previousNode is your current node (self)
```